# VM with version 1.6.0 does not have multidex support : Unable to find application Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_23 or Xamarin.Android.Platform

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-multidex

I had created a small app.
When I try running the app on genymotion emulator it gives a Pop-up "**Unfortunately My App has stopped**"

---

Application Output :

```
Forwarding debugger port 8834
Detecting existing process
[MultiDex] VM with version 1.6.0 does not have multidex support
[MultiDex] install
[MultiDex] MultiDexExtractor.load(/data/app/purposecolor.purposecolor-2.apk, false)
[MultiDex] Detected that extraction must be performed.
[MultiDex] load found 0 secondary dex files
[MultiDex] install done
[AndroidRuntime] Shutting down VM
[AndroidRuntime] FATAL EXCEPTION: main
[AndroidRuntime] java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider mono.MonoRuntimeProvider: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find application Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_23 or Xamarin.Android.Platform!
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4563)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4190)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4132)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:130)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
[AndroidRuntime]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
[AndroidRuntime]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
[AndroidRuntime]    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
[AndroidRuntime] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find application Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_23 or Xamarin.Android.Platform!
[AndroidRuntime]    at mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.attachInfo(MonoRuntimeProvider.java:38)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4560)
[AndroidRuntime]    ... 12 more
[AndroidRuntime] Caused by: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: Xamarin.Android.Platform
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:210)
[AndroidRuntime]    at mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.attachInfo(MonoRuntimeProvider.java:32)
[AndroidRuntime]    ... 13 more
[Process] Sending signal. PID: 1845 SIG: 9
```

---

Compile using Android Version : `Use Latest Platform (API Level 23(Xamarin.Android v6.0 Support))`

Minimum Android to Target : `API Level 16(Xamarin.Android v4.1 Support)`

Target Android Version : `API Level 16(Xamarin.Android v4.1 Support)`

Comment: `load found 0 secondary dex files`. This won't solve your problem, but why do you use multidex if you don't need to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling `Multi-Dex` in Project options solved my problem.

**Project** --> **Options** --> **Android Build** --> **General** --> Uncheck **Enable Multi-Dex**

---

Thanks @AlexLipov for giving me hint

> `[MultiDex] load found 0 secondary dex files`